# variables and parameter mistake from python sqlite3 code (missing whitespace around operator)

Tags: python, sqlite

I write some codes for my database and now I am tring to return some database command with different parameter with include from x and y.

This is my variables x and y.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
x = ""
y = ""
cur= conn.cursor()
```

Honestly. I am not really understand is it correct that i just do the parameter like

```
 x = ""
 y = ""
```

Then my variable sql is to select sqlcommand from my db with x and y variable
and i have found some error that in "+ x +"  and "+ y +"

```
sql= "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type ="+ x +"  or  function ="+ y +"　ORDER BY key ASC"


def read():
 for row in cur.execute(sql):
   print(row)
```

After i press x it shows that

```
missing whitespace around operator
```

What should I do for further correction?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have no space between `=` and `x` or `=` and `y` add a space between both use:

```
sql  = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type = "+ x +"  or  function = "+ y +"　ORDER BY key ASC"
```

Or:

```
sql  = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type = {}  or  function = {}　ORDER BY key ASC".format(x,y)
```

Your code looks something like the following:

```
In [31]: x = "foo"

In [32]: "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type ="+ x
Out[32]: 'SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type =foo <- no space
```

'

Answer (score 0):

As Padraic Cunningham said it, you are missing a space before your variables, right after the `=` sign.

`sql= "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type = "+ x +"  or  function = "+ y +"　ORDER BY key ASC"`

This will work but can be **UNSAFE** and is, therefore, strongly discouraged as it could lead to SQL injections.

Instead you should do that:

```
sql= "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE type = ?  or  function = ?　ORDER BY key ASC"

def read():
 for row in cur.execute(sql, (x,y)):
   print(row)
```